# combine and count itemset apriori with mysql

Tags: mysql, apriori

i have table like this:

```
`transaction_id       item`  
`1                    milk`                
`1                    chocolate`  
`1                    fanta`  
`2                    jam`  
`2                    lolipop`  
`2                    ice cream`  
`2                    bread`   
`3                    bread`   
`3                    jam`  
`4                    milk`   
`4                    snack`  
`4                    chocolate`   
`5                    snack`  
`5                    fanta``
```

i want to ask, how to combine item into k-itemset and then count the support with mysql??

Comment: if you know apriori algorithm you should know what i mean

Comment: Derived by logic, without observed facts